# Granting privileges to user on AWS RDS Insance

Tags: database, oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I am currently importing a dump file inside RDS Oracle 12C instance using `impdp` command.

Prior to that it is required to create few users & grant them required privileges.

I have following statements that I use on other non-rds databases.

```
GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO "USERNAME"
GRANT "RESOURCE" TO "USERNAME"
GRANT "CONNECT" TO "USERNAME"
GRANT "EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE" TO "USERNAME"
```

When I run these prior to import, these commands return `grant succeeded`.

Now, when I run `impdp`, I get following errors in log:

```
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT                               
ORA-31685: Object type SYSTEM_GRANT:"USRNAME" failed due to insufficient privileges. 
Failing sql is:  

GRANT UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO "USERNAME"

ORA-39083: Object type ROLE_GRANT failed to create with error:                  
ORA-01924: role 'CONNECT' not granted or does not exist  
Failing sql is:   

GRANT "CONNECT" TO "USERNAME"
```

Same for other privileges as well.

I am running these commands using `admin` user that was created while spinning up the instance.

I have seen there's a different way of granting in AWS RDS [on this link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.System.html#Appendix.Oracle.CommonDBATasks.TransferPrivileges)

How do I map that with what I'm trying to achieve here?

Comment: For those who have also run into this issue but don't need Oracle 12, note that this does not seem to be a problem with RDS Oracle 11.2

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you NOT to use RESOURCE and CONNECT roles. These were popular back in 1990s as they contained the most common privileges one might need. However, *best practice* says that you should grant only privileges that are required for a certain user.

CONNECT nowadays contains only CREATE SESSION. RESOURCE contains several CREATE *something* privileges (table, procedure, trigger, ...) (query DBA_SYS_PRIVS to see them all). Do you *really* need CREATE CLUSTER? If not, well, don't grant it.

Try to add those privileges separately:

```
grant create session to username;
grant create table to username;
grant unlimited tablespace to username;
grant *whichever additional privilege USERNAME requires*;
```

Finally, just in case you didn't read it, this is the [Importing Data into Oracle on Amazon RDS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Oracle.Procedural.Importing.html) documentation, have a look; perhaps you'll find something useful.

Comment: I did all of that. 
My problem is, even though I assign all grants prior to import, it still results in above errors.

Answer (score 0):

Your case deals with a very specific situation Oracle Database permission to user. To grant a ALREADY EXISTING USER such a privilege (QUOTA UNLIMITED) is has to be done with this command:
ALTER USER xxxx_userName QUOTA UNLIMITED ON yyyy_tablespaceName;